# Screen turns into standby and doesn't turn back on without any reason (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, graphics, screen

I am currently working with Ubuntu 18.04 on a - already quite old - custom build desktop pc. 
Even though this computer is running some analyses the screen sometimes turns unexpectedly into standby. Whatever I do nothing helps to turn the screen back on. Only hard-resetting the computer and waiting for several minutes to hours helps such that I can see anything on my screen again.

I even turned the screen lock function to 'never' and it just now happened again. Also, the auto suspend function is turned off.

I am quite out of ideas what to try next and since I don't really know if Ubuntu crashes as other screens don't seem to work as well when this happens.

It would be so great if anyone could help me figure out the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Furthermore, I hope that I didn't miss any equal questions - the ones I found had quite different problems (at least from my understanding)

All the best,
PS

Comment: Is it possible that it's your display doing this, and not the OS? Try checking the settings on the display itself, to confirm this is not the problem.

Comment: @TomBrossman the screen settings seem fine. Although, I must be honest that I cannot find anything closely related to standby settings or related.

Comment: I have the same issue in both 16.04.5 and 18.04. Once the screen turn off, it doesn't come back on until hard reboot.

Comment: I also have this problem in Ubuntu 20.04. I used to have it, reinstalled the OS and it stopped doing it, but I just got a new graphics card which involved reinstalling the graphics drivers and it has started doing it again.